# Convex open set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and let $C$ be a compact convex subset of $X$. Is it true that for every open set $V$ (in $X$) containing $C$, there exists a convex open set $U$ contained in $V$ and contains $C$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I should have written $C$ to be compact convex, which I have edited now.

Comment: Just an idea which may or may not work: the distance from $C$ to $A^C$ is positive. Perhaps if you cover $C$ with open balls, each contained in $A$, of small enough radii, the convex hull of their union will be contained in $A$.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMitra! Intuitively it seems to be right. However, I am finding it difficult to prove it rigorously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the convex subsets $C$ and $B_\epsilon(0)$, then $C+B_\epsilon(0)$ is also convex since $\forall a,b\in C, \forall x,y\in B_\epsilon(0)$, $$(1-t)(a+x)+t(b+y)=(1-t)a+tb+(1-t)x+ty\in C+B_\epsilon(0)$$ Since $C\subset V$, each of its points $x\in C$ is covered by some $B_r(x)\subset V$, so by a standard compactness argument there is a finite subcover and an $\epsilon>0$ such that $C+B_\epsilon(0)\subset V$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $C+{1 \over n} B(0,1) \cap V^c$ is non empty for all $n$. Then there are $c_n\in C, u_n \in B(0,1)$ such that $c_n+{1 \over n}u_n \in V^c$. By
passing to a subsequence as necessary, we can assume that $c_n \to c \in C$
and since $V^c$ is closed we see that $c \in V^c$ which is a contradiction.

Hence there is some $n$ such that $C+{1 \over n} B(0,1)$ (which is convex and open) is contained in $V$.